# In backprop/gradient descent, why isn't the reciprocal of gradient used when updating weights?

Tags: gradient-descent, backpropagation

I've seeing almost all tutorials on backprop stating the following for weight update:

$$
W_n = W_{n-1} - lr \times L\frac{dL}{dW}
$$

Since $\frac{dL}{dW}$ is the influence of $W$ on $L$, and we are deriving the change of $W$ from $L$, shouldn't it be the following?

$$
W_n = W_{n-1} - lr \times L\frac{dW}{dL}
$$